# Javascript regex split on first slash

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this: "one/two/three/four" and I just want to return:

```
"one"
"two/three/four"
```

I'm not the greatest with regex expressions to split on, so was wondering if someone could help.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```
var components = "one/two/three/four".split("/");
console.log(components[0]);
console.log(components.slice(1).join("/"));
```

This will print:

```
one
two/three/four
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the `1` argument to `split` limits the returned array to one element. Remove it and you should be fine.

Comment: @torazaburo You're right, I seriously have *no idea* why that `1` was there. I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this will work as well (although it does return an extra blank string):

```
"one/two/three/four".split(/\/(.+)?/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf()

```
<script>

function mySplit(s) {
    var pos = s.indexOf('/');
    if (pos != -1) return [s.substring(0,pos), s.substring(pos+1)];
    else return s;
}

console.log(mySplit('one/two/three/four'));
console.log(mySplit('test'));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regexp as follows

```
var regex   = /(.*?)\/(.*)/;
var string  = "one/two/three/four";
var matches = string.match(regex);

console.log(matches[1], matches{2])

>> one two/three/four
```

In English, the regexp reads:

- Match any string up to but not including a slash
- Match everything after that